# check directory for files not in mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, file

I have this code which checks if there are any filenames in my database table "files" which are not in the directory "video/test". I have been trying to edit this code so that it does the opposite i.e it checks if there are any filenames in the directory "video/test" which are not in the database table "files". I am having some trouble switching the content to the other side of the clause. I'm getting mysql syntax errors. Can anyone help me out with this

```
$filenames = scandir("video/test");
$sql = sprintf( 'SELECT * FROM files WHERE filename not in ("%s")', implode( '","', $filenames ) );
```

Comment: you mean something like this? $sql = sprintf( 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM files WHERE filename in ("%s")', implode( '","', $filenames ) );

Comment: Can you post the specific error you get?

Comment: `var_dump($sql)` and you'll see what's going on.

Comment: the errors are php related mainly, just like, unexpected (character) parse errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

```
$filenames = scandir("video/test");
$files = implode(",", $filenames );
$sql = sprintf( "SELECT * FROM files WHERE filename not in (".$files.")" );
```

Give it a try ;)

Saludos.